# VBA if value in range 1 then value in range 2 multiple by -1

Tags: vba, excel

This is columns C and G in excel

```
($12,843.63)    40100
($9,584.60)     53450
($67,933.38)    53500
($2,615.56)     54900
$43,378.11      72100
$607.91         72100
$14,843.94      72400
$286.62         72440
$3,283.73       72500
$46.50          72500
$9,392.28       75400
$3,754.16       81100
$540.00         81300
$6,186.20       82110
$4,658.21       82140
$13,576.61      82160
$35,467.33      82200
$196.18         82600
$10.83          83100
$34.84          83140
$22,535.60      85240
$691.47         85260
$145.00         85300
($45.00)        85980
$1,010.00       86500
$32,249.97      99150
($8,992.44)     99200
$0.00           72100
```

'If the value in the second range is between 40000 and 60000 then the value in the first range is multiplied by -1

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngsear As Range
Set rng = Range("D15:D" & lastrow)
Set rngsear = Range("C15:C" & lastrow)
If rng.Value >= (40000 < 60000) Then
rngsear.Value = -rngsear.Value
End If
```

It says I have a run-time error '91'
Object variable or With block variable not set
I'm not sure how to make it loop properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to do it without loops:

```
Sub change()
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngsear As Range
Dim lastrow As Long
With ActiveSheet
    lastrow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("D15:D" & lastrow)
    Set rngsear = .Range("C15:C" & lastrow)
    rngsear.Value = .Evaluate("IF((" & rng.Address & " >= 40000)*(" & rng.Address & " < 60000)," & rngsear.Address & " * -1," & rngsear.Address & ")")
End With

End Sub
```